# node js architecture instantiating a module that gets access token for each user concurrency

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, architecture

How can I achieve concurrency in this situation so Node Module can serve multiple users?

I'm developing two pieces of a codebase for a client application.

1. Node App
2. Node Module (collection of classes)

**Node app** provides `credentials` for **user1** to **Node Module** that in turns gets the `access_token` and then uses **(both token and credentials)** for subsequent calls.

I prefer that **Node Module** takes care of managing the access token and credentials for all calls but then it limits to 1 user since node runs in a single process.

One of my Node module classes looks like this, (see the issue) I'm providing credentials and authentication (token) to each function call besides other params (not a good interface). Wondering if this can be any better so I can have cleaner interface of each function call besides achieving concurrency.

```
var Entity = function() {};

Entity.prototype.requestList = function(credentials, authentication, publication, entityType) {
    return new Proimse(function(resolve, reject){
    });
};

module.exports = new Entity();
```

**Edit**

One solution that just came to me is to return the `access_token` (3rd party token) besides the `authToken` (my app token) back to the client, so clients cache them and send them along with each subsequent request so server side code doesn't have to maintain or manage it. Concurrency achieved.

Comment: Are you using express ?

Comment: yes I'm using expressjs

Comment: Why don't you use middleware ? http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html.

Comment: I understand middleware but can't connect the suggestion to my app, can you please elaborate more on this, like how?

Comment: Basically you will have an authentication middleware, this middleware will use the request as parameters. 
It will check if there is an Authentication token in the request header, if there is Authentication token then the middleware will check the token and identify the user using the token, you can for example set an req.user object containing the user object. 
Then on your controller you can get the user using the req.user.
Do you need more details ?